# Solving Simple Mixed Fraction problem?

Tags: fractions

How do you wrap your head around mixed fraction, does anyone knows how to figure out, can someone give me an example how it can be solved?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean when you say "how it can be solved?"  Do you mean how can a number like $3\frac58$ can be expressed as a fraction (not mixed)?

Comment: PLease give an example of what do you want to solve.So that it will be easy to explain

Comment: When I mean "how it can be solved" I want to know from how the numbers comes together from start to finish in an easy logical way to form it together in a way I can understand?

Comment: Are either of the answers below helpful in that way?

Comment: It is, Now the answers is flowing to me clearly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a +\frac bc =  \frac {a\times c}c + \frac bc = \frac{(a\times c) + b}{c} $$

What we do first is like when finding a common denominator between two fractions, only in $a$ above, we have $a = \dfrac a1$:

We multiply $a = \dfrac a1$ by $\dfrac cc = 1$, to get $\dfrac a1 \times \dfrac cc = \;\dfrac{a\times c}{c}\;$ and then add that to the fraction $\dfrac bc$.

For example

$$3 \frac 58\; = \;3 + \frac 58\; = \;\frac{3 \times 8}{8} + \frac 58\; = \;\frac{(3\times 8)+ 5}{8}\; = \;\frac{24 + 5}{8} \;= \;\frac{29}{8}$$

Comment: Good call, you did the general case followed by an example +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

$$2 \frac{3}{11}=\frac{2 \cdot 11}{11}+\frac3{11}=\frac{22}{11}+\frac3{11}=\frac{25}{11}$$

Or conversely,

$$\frac{11}3=\frac{11-3 \cdot 3}{3}+\frac{3 \cdot 3}{3}=\frac{11-9}{3}+\frac{9}{3}=\frac{2}{3}+3=3 \frac{2}3$$.

In general,

$$x+\frac{y}{z}=\frac{x \cdot z}{z}+\frac{y}{z}=\frac{x \cdot z +y}z$$ and vice versa.

In most cases you'll encounter $y<z$.